# What's this mate called?

Tags: checkmate, patterns

I've blundered and had this played on me before. Is there a specific name for the mate?

```
[FEN "8/8/8/8/1n6/8/qPP5/1KR5 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Let's call it "Damascus Mate"  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not have any special name. I have been playing for 40 years, and I have never seen it given any specific name.

Here is a very good [list of named mates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate_pattern), and as you can see, your position is not among them.

Answer (score -8):

The only  real  name it has is <<   CHECK mate!   >>

Maybe somebody somewhere gave it a label, but if so it did not stick.
Most likely during  a speed game and somebody said somely like the patzer got mated. So maybe locally, for a brief time, it was the patzers mate.

Comment: The answer Phishmaster already posted is more thorough and more helpful, this comes off as just noise. This would probably be ok as a comment (though i am not sure, it's kind of borderline, but there is some tolerance for this kind of thing), but it is not surprising to see it downvoted as an answer. My advice is, post answers that are constructive, and that address the question in a way that other answers have not already done.

Comment: whatever dood .  it answered the question with info that phishy did not include.  and is just as accurate for the actual question.  we both gave some alternate elaboration.  this sounds more like its personal than  factual or useful when answers get downvoted.

Comment: You are missing the point. stackexchange values answers and minimizes noise. I think you are knowledgeable, but not clued in to how things work here.

Comment: you are missing the point.  all valid answers add value.  there is not one  correct answer.  the sum of all valid data would approach the correct answer and perhaps even achieve it occasionally.